# Ubuntu SDK Error 'could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb".'

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml, html5, sdk

I am trying to write my first ubuntu app using the Ubuntu SDK but keep running into an error. This error turns up both with QML and HTML5 apps. I am trying this just on the template for both project types.

When I try and run the app I get:

```
Starting /usr/bin/ubuntu-html5-app-launcher...
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb".
Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
The program has unexpectedly finished.
/usr/bin/ubuntu-html5-app-launcher crashed
```

What makes no sense is that I can open the HTML5 app using the ubuntu-html5-app-launcher from the command line in the project folder. I am merely trying to display the template app that it opens with a new project so there shouldnt be any issues from me interfering.

I dont think I am missing any Qt XCB packages and I installed the following that I found online as a possible solution to the problem.

```
sudo apt-get install "^libxcb.*" libx11-xcb-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libxrender-dev libxi-dev
```

Am I missing some something in the install? something in the setup of a project? I installed the sdk from the app store (and once before from the command line) and neither methods was any more successful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error by launching a scope app. I had to install `qt5-default` then configure the QT runtime in the Desktop Kit target.